# Loop keeps freezing midway through the code

Tags: python, loops, freeze

I'm trying to create a code that cleans up a file I have so I can use it as data, but every time I run it, it freezes mid way, at "173529" every single time. The only reason I can think of is that I'm overworking my laptop and the console can't catch up or something. I can't see any reason or error that would cause such an issue, so I'm hoping somebody can identify it for me...

(Before all this is just a bunch of variables that edit the code and clean it up a bit before the main filtering process. The print codes are just there for debugging purposes. 'cn' is character number value, and 'nil' is number in list value)

```
import time
import re
import is
os.system("color")

 def spamp2():
    userList = []
    countertls = 0
    counterpus = 0
    a = open(document, "r+", encoding='utf8').read().replace("[breaker]", "")
    b = a.replace(" ","\n")
    c = b.replace(":heart:", "")
    d = c.replace(r":\w+:", "")
    e = d.replace(":", "\n")
    f = e.replace("  ", " ")
    g = f.replace("  ", " ")
    h = g.replace(" ", "")
    i = h.replace("", " ")
    j = i.replace("", "")
    k = j.replace(":", "")
    l = k.splitlines()
    m = [*set(l)]
    print("Running...")
    numinList = len(m)
    time.sleep(5)
    while numinList != 0:
        for i in m:
            if "" in i:
                ##  Character Number Value
                cn = len(i)
                ##  Number In List Value
                nil = len(m)
                if cn > 22:
                    m.remove(i)
                    ##countertls+1
                    print("\x1B[1mStringChar22+ Removed\x1B[0m")
                    print("CN Value = "+str(cn))
                    print("NuminList Value = "+str(nil)+"\n")
                    
                else:
                    userList.append(i)
                    m.remove(i)
                    ##counterpus+1
                    print("\x1B[1mPotentialUsername Added\x1B[0m")
                    print("CN Value = "+str(cn))
                    print("NuminList Value = "+str(nil)+"\n")

    else:
        print("Printing...")
        time.sleep(8)
        with open("tempy.txt", "a+", encoding='utf8') as tmp:
            tmp.truncate()
            tmp.write(userList)
            ##print("\nCharTLS Removed: "+countertls)
            ##print("CounterPUS Added: "+counterpus)
            print("\n   Proccess Completed  ")
```

Here's a sample of the data (Changed the usernames to conceal identity. It's just a big text file of a Discord log without any new lines):

```
Username: the problem with that was that it flew into the street    Nameuser: that's rought dude    Username: thankfully it didn't cause an accident otherwise it wouldn't be as fun [breaker]  but hooray for coke fireworks [breaker]  :partying_face:
```

If anything else needs to be provided, please let me know.

Comment: Why would `numinList > 0` ever become `false`?

Comment: It's hard to reproduce the problem. 1. We don't have the necessary imports. 2. `l` is not defined. 3. `userList` is not defined. 4. We don't have the file to process. On Stack Overflow we love [mre]s

Comment: Change `while numinList > 0:` to `while len(m) > 0:`

Comment: There's no point in having an `else:` block on a loop if there's no `break` statement. Its only purpose is to distinguish between normal ending of the loop and exiting with `break`.

Comment: Don't modify the list `m` while you're in a `for i in m:` loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it

Comment: BTW: there is no need to give each thing a new name. If you never use something again, you can just write `a = a.replace(...)` and then `a = a.replace(...)` again

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're not recalculating `numinList` inside the `while` loop so it never decreases. Therefore, you have an infinite loop.

Also it would be helpful to know more about what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making this way more complicated than necessary.

```
m = [name for name in m if "" in name]
userList = [name for name in m if len(name) > 22]
print("Printing...")
os.sleep(8)
with open("tempy.txt", "w", encoding='utf8') as tmp:
    tmp.write("\n".join(userList) + "\n")
```

Use `w` mode when opening the file to truncate automatically before writing. And the argument to `tmp.write()` has to be a string, not a list.